# Using functions on link opened through search page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have created a search page. When the user clicks on a link he will be redirected to that page. Can I run a function on that page? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

Add script tag just above the closing tag of body.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//first define the function

function hello()
{
console.log("Hello new page");

}

hello(); // call the function
</script>
</body>
```

Now whenever this page gets loaded, this javascript function will run first.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", yourFunction);`

if you want to wait for external resources to load, you can use `load` instead of `DOMContentLoaded`